# Is it possible to map a list within a main list into the main list?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let’s say I have:

```
List<Thing> myList = …
```

And `Thing` is a class that includes:

```
String a;
List<String> b;
…
```

Is it possible to map myList in a way that generates a `List<String>` that includes all `a` and all `b`?

I want to end up with a `List<String>` with all values of `a` and all values of `b`.

Something like:

```
myList.map((e) => ????).toList()
```

Currently what I do is create a separate List secondList and then loop through both lists like this:

```
myList.forEach((e) {
  secondList.add(e.a);
  e.b.forEach((x) => secondList.add(x));
});
```

But it’s a bit cumbersome. Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expand` to convert these data into single list

```
List<String> secondList = list.expand((element) => [element.a, ...element.b]).toList();
```

Or, you can also use `for` and `addAll`

```
myList.forEach((e) {
  secondList.add(e.a);
  secondList.addAll(e.b);
});
```

Comment: Expand was the simplest that worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `Iterable.map` usually can be replaced with collection-`for`.  In this case, that would be much simpler since that also would let you use the spread (`...`) operator:

```dart
var everything = [
  for (var thing in myList)
    ...[thing.a, ...thing.b],
];
```